# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from Apple Subthread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, nszombie

All of a sudden, I receive this EXC_BAD_ACCESS and NSZombie isn't saying anything.
Anyone have an effective way to debug and eliminate this issue?

[image]

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what is happening. What are you trying to do that causes this error?

Comment: That's the only information I see. I'm trying to load a new view, and I can see in NSLog, that it succeeds. Then, all of a sudden, is crashes. I've tried on a different computer, where it shows NSZombie information, but here the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs at different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be following issues:-

> 1) First check in your code in which line it is happening.
>
> 2) It happens due to improper bindings in the xib as well.